# Triggering change doesn't update vuejs binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-chosen, vue.js

If you change the value on the first dropdown it working fine but not on the second one. See the example below.

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    fruits: ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Orange']
  },
  ready: function() {
    $('.chosen-select').chosen({ width: '20%' });
  },
  watch: {
    fruits: function () {
       $('.chosen-select').trigger('chosen:updated');
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.chosen-select{ display: initial !important } // for debuging purpose
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.4.2/chosen.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.4.2/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <select class="chosen-select" v-model="fruit">
    <option v-for="fruit in fruits" v-bind:value="fruit" v-text="fruit"></option>
  </select>
  <p>You like {{fruit}}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Chosen plug-in is creating a new dropdown, so it isn't watched properly by Vue.  You'll have to manually change Vue in the `change` event on chosen:

```
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    fruit:"Apple",
    fruits: ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Orange']
  },
  ready: function() {
    $('.chosen-select').chosen({ width: '20%' }).change(function(e){
      this.fruit = e.currentTarget.value;
    }.bind(this));
  }
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/89sbqy3b/